# Saving each feature symbology to a image using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, vector-layer

I am attempting to write a plugin to export a LayerVector (Points) to images.
I need to get the symbology of each point to export as images (PNG).

My intention here is to create a new file containing the attributes of the LayerVector. I want to add one column `'icon_url'` with the name of the image that will be used as symbology for the point.
The following code works for some symbologies, but some types the `originalSymbolForFeature` return `None`.

How to draw the visual representation used in QGIS and export it to a image?

```
import time;
layer = iface.mapCanvas().layers()[0]


clonedLayer = layer.clone()
layerRenderer = clonedLayer.renderer()
renderContext = QgsRenderContext()
renderContext.setUseAdvancedEffects(True)
renderContext.setFlags(QgsRenderContext.Flag.RenderBlocking | QgsRenderContext.Flag.Antialiasing)
imageList = list()
iconField = QgsField('icon_url', QVariant.String, 'text')
clonedLayer.startEditing()
res = clonedLayer.addAttribute(iconField)
clonedLayer.commitChanges()
clonedLayer.startEditing()
for feature in clonedLayer.getFeatures():
    layerRenderer.startRender(renderContext, clonedLayer.fields())
    symbol = layerRenderer.originalSymbolForFeature(feature, renderContext)
    layerRenderer.stopRender(renderContext)
    curImage = symbol.asImage(QSize(32, 32))
    try:
        imgIndex = imageList.index(curImage)
    except Exception as e:
        imageList.append(curImage)
        imgIndex = len(imageList) - 1
    feature.setAttribute("icon_url", './' + str(imgIndex) + ".png")
    clonedLayer.updateFeature(feature)


clonedLayer.commitChanges()
wgs_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326')
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(clonedLayer, 'C:/Users/danilo/Downloads/symbol/myjson_danilo_.json',
                                                  'utf-8', wgs_crs, 'CSV', layerOptions=['GEOMETRY=AS_XY'])
```

Answer (score 2):

In fact the function `originalSymbolForFeature` only work for some symbology types (Strange behaviour yet nothing about it in documentation).
I've just changed to `originalSymbolsForFeature` and everything worked well.

```
    symbol = layerRenderer.originalSymbolsForFeature(feature, renderContext)
    if len(symbol) <= 0:
        continue
    else:
        symbol = symbol[0]
```

PS: Using QGIS 3.10.2